# JAVAFX load exception while opening a new stage

Tags: java, javafx

Hello guys am new to javafx, i have been working on a simple employee app... but  have this painful error when i click on a button meant to open a new stage. Here is my code

```
package employee;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application{
private static Stage primaryStage;
private static BorderPane mainLayout;
enter code here

public static void main(String[]args){
    launch(args);
    }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
this.primaryStage.setTitle("Employee App");

    showMainView();
    showMainItems();
}

      private void showMainView() throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainView.fxml"));
        mainLayout = loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

     public static void showMainItems() throws IOException {



        FXMLLoader loader;
        loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/MainItems.fxml"));
        BorderPane mainItemsLayout;
        mainItemsLayout = loader.load();
        mainLayout.setCenter(mainItemsLayout);

    }


     public static void showElectricalScene() throws IOException {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("electrical/ElectricalDep.fxml"));
        BorderPane electricalLayout = loader.load();
        mainLayout.setCenter(electricalLayout);

    }

     public static void showMechanicalScene() throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("mechanical/MechanicalDep.fxml"));
    BorderPane mechanicalLayout = loader.load();
    mainLayout.setCenter(mechanicalLayout);

}


     public static void showAddButtonStage() throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/addNewEmployee.fxml"));
    BorderPane addButton = loader.load();

   // BorderPane root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("view/addNewEmployee.fxml"));
    Stage addDialogStage= new Stage();
    addDialogStage.setTitle("Add New Employee");
    addDialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    addDialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
    Scene scene= new Scene(addButton);
    addDialogStage.setScene(scene);
    addDialogStage.showAndWait();

}

}
```

here is the error

---

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException:                 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1768)
at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1765)
... 47 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:/C:/Users/Dorcas%20Adegboye/IdeaProjects/EmployeeApp/out/production/EmployeeApp/employee/view/addNewEmployee.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3230)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3191)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3164)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3140)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3120)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
at employee.Main.showAddButtonStage(Main.java:82)
at employee.view.MainViewController.addBtn(MainViewController.java:26)
... 57 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:601)
at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2513)
... 66 more
```

GOOD answers appreciated.

Comment: The error is in your FXML file (`addNewEmployee.fxml`), which appears to be empty.

Comment: Thanks, that exactly was where the error was. I had an empty (addNewEmployee.fxml)

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450 generally helpful for using the stack trace to troubleshoot problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the resource with the full package, e.g.:

```
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("/employee/view/MainView.fxml"));
```